# Inverse Fourier transform using laplace

Tags: fourier-analysis, inverse, laplace-transform

We have to solve the inverse FT of $$\frac{1}{1+4w^2}$$ I tried to do the synthesis but got mediocre results. However this term screams laplace to me. I can see a sine in there. The last lecture they actually showed us a proof how we perform a fourier transform using laplace but not whether there is a similar thing for the inverse. I still have difficulties grasping the whole concept, so I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: this was discussed dozens of times on this site...try to use the search option a little bit mote